# How to collect terms with z-derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

my equations are very long (several pages). Here I will provide simple example:

```
eq = (g[x, y, z, t])^2*D[D[f[x, y, z, t], {x, 1}] {z, 1}] + \[Alpha]*
f[x, y, z, t]*D[D[g[x, y, z, t], {y, 1}], {z, 2}] + 
g[x, y, z, t]*D[D[f[x, y, z, t], {t, 1}] {z, 2}]+D[f[x,y,z,t],{z,2}]
```

So, it has several functions, constant parameters, and consists of the sum of some terms. Each term is the product of some number of these functions and it's derivatives.

I want to collect, or sort, these terms according to `z`-derivative. So, first, I want to sort these terms according to the highest z-derivative of the function `f[x,y,z,t]`. So, in the example above, first term should be `g[x, y, z, t]*D[D[f[x, y, z, t], {t, 1}] {z, 2}]+D[f[x,y,z,t],{z,2}]`, as long as it has second derivatives of the function `f[x,y,z,t]` over `z`. After that it should be `(g[x, y, z, t])^2*D[D[f[x, y, z, t], {x, 1}] {z, 1}]`, and then `f[x, y, z, t]*D[D[g[x, y, z, t], {y, 1}], {z, 2}]`.

Note, that the derivative could be taken over several arguments, like `g[x, y, z, t]*D[D[f[x, y, z, t], {t, 1}] {z, 2}]`.

I looked through the examples of `Collect`, but didn't find a way to specify `z`-derivative, as a second argument. Also it would be good, if you point out, how to show only the terms with `z` derivatives.

Thanks in advance,
Mikhail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is an easier and shorter way of doing this so consider this a starting point.

A strange thing I noticed is that when I copied and pasted your equation into a notebook it turned into a list.

```
eq = g[x, y, z, t]^2*D[D[f[x, y, z, t], {x, 1}] {z, 1}] + 
   α*f[x, y, z, t]*D[D[g[x, y, z, t], {y, 1}], {z, 2}] + 
  g[x, y, z, t]*D[D[f[x, y, z, t], {t, 1}] {z, 2}] + 
  D[f[x, y, z, t], {z, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I continue to be mystified by this however we need to take it into account.

**Step 1 - Strip curly brackets**

eq = eq[[1]]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Step 2 - Break it into parts**

eqList = eq[[#]] & /@ Range[Length[eq]]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This effectively breaks it at the plus sign.

**Step 3 - Sort the parts**

This is the significant portion. We will use the value of the `zth` derivative to do the sorting.

```
sortedEqList = 
 Sort[eqList, 
  Total@Cases[#1, 
      Derivative[i_Integer, j_Integer, k_Integer, l_Integer][f | g][x,
         y, z, t] -> k, {0, Infinity}] > 
    Total@Cases[#2, 
      Derivative[i_Integer, j_Integer, k_Integer, l_Integer][f | g][x,
         y, z, t] -> k, {0, Infinity}] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Step 4 - Join the sorted parts**

If you merely rejoin the parts using `Plus` they will be sorted back to the original order so use `Inactive`.

```
Inactive[Plus] @@ sortedEqList
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That perfectly works for me!

Comment: Advise that you wait a couple of days before accepting. It is highly probable that someone will provide a better answer. You should select the **best** answer, not the fastest.

Comment: Got it, thanks.