# Collect partial derivatives and rewrite them with delta/nabla

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, output-formatting

Ultimately, I wish to get the higher generalized product rule for Laplacian.
That is, we have
$\Delta(fg)=f\Delta g+2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g+g\Delta f$
but what is $\Delta^n(fg)$?

I am tying to guess the general formula using Mathematica.

We get

```
Laplacian[f[x, y, z] g[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

(*
===>

```
2 (f^(0,0,1))[x,y,z] (g^(0,0,1))[x,y,z]+g[x,y,z] (f^(0,0,2))[x,y,z]+f[x,y,z] (g^(0,0,2))[x,y,z]+2 (f^(0,1,0))[x,y,z] (g^(0,1,0))[x,y,z]+g[x,y,z] (f^(0,2,0))[x,y,z]+f[x,y,z] (g^(0,2,0))[x,y,z]+2 (f^(1,0,0))[x,y,z] (g^(1,0,0))[x,y,z]+g[x,y,z] (f^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]+f[x,y,z] (g^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]
```

*)

**Is there a way to automatically rewrite this as more readable "$f\Delta g+2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g+g\Delta f$"?**

Further,

```
Laplacian[Laplacian[f[x, y, z] g[x, y, z], {x, y, z}],{x,y,z}]
```

(*
===>

```
6 (f^(0,0,2))[x,y,z] (g^(0,0,2))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(0,0,1))[x,y,z] (f^(0,0,3))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(0,0,1))[x,y,z] (g^(0,0,3))[x,y,z]+g[x,y,z] (f^(0,0,4))[x,y,z]+f[x,y,z] (g^(0,0,4))[x,y,z]+8 (f^(0,1,1))[x,y,z] (g^(0,1,1))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(0,1,0))[x,y,z] (f^(0,1,2))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(0,1,0))[x,y,z] (g^(0,1,2))[x,y,z]+2 (g^(0,0,2))[x,y,z] (f^(0,2,0))[x,y,z]+2 (f^(0,0,2))[x,y,z] (g^(0,2,0))[x,y,z]+6 (f^(0,2,0))[x,y,z] (g^(0,2,0))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(0,0,1))[x,y,z] (f^(0,2,1))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(0,0,1))[x,y,z] (g^(0,2,1))[x,y,z]+2 g[x,y,z] (f^(0,2,2))[x,y,z]+2 f[x,y,z] (g^(0,2,2))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(0,1,0))[x,y,z] (f^(0,3,0))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(0,1,0))[x,y,z] (g^(0,3,0))[x,y,z]+g[x,y,z] (f^(0,4,0))[x,y,z]+f[x,y,z] (g^(0,4,0))[x,y,z]+8 (f^(1,0,1))[x,y,z] (g^(1,0,1))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(1,0,0))[x,y,z] (f^(1,0,2))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(1,0,0))[x,y,z] (g^(1,0,2))[x,y,z]+8 (f^(1,1,0))[x,y,z] (g^(1,1,0))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(1,0,0))[x,y,z] (f^(1,2,0))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(1,0,0))[x,y,z] (g^(1,2,0))[x,y,z]+2 (g^(0,0,2))[x,y,z] (f^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]+2 (g^(0,2,0))[x,y,z] (f^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]+2 (f^(0,0,2))[x,y,z] (g^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]+2 (f^(0,2,0))[x,y,z] (g^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]+6 (f^(2,0,0))[x,y,z] (g^(2,0,0))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(0,0,1))[x,y,z] (f^(2,0,1))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(0,0,1))[x,y,z] (g^(2,0,1))[x,y,z]+2 g[x,y,z] (f^(2,0,2))[x,y,z]+2 f[x,y,z] (g^(2,0,2))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(0,1,0))[x,y,z] (f^(2,1,0))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(0,1,0))[x,y,z] (g^(2,1,0))[x,y,z]+2 g[x,y,z] (f^(2,2,0))[x,y,z]+2 f[x,y,z] (g^(2,2,0))[x,y,z]+4 (g^(1,0,0))[x,y,z] (f^(3,0,0))[x,y,z]+4 (f^(1,0,0))[x,y,z] (g^(3,0,0))[x,y,z]+g[x,y,z] (f^(4,0,0))[x,y,z]+f[x,y,z] (g^(4,0,0))[x,y,z]
```

*)

**Is there a way to rewrite this with $\Delta^2$, $\Delta$, or $\nabla$ etc. if applicable?**

I bet somewhere around this [How to collect terms with z-derivative?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97455/how-to-collect-terms-with-z-derivative)
but I have no clue...

(I am assuming I can apply the possible answer to Laplacian[Laplacian[Laplacian...etc.)

Comment: Please take time to format your code: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Instead of guessing, you could read about the generalized Leibniz rule.

Comment: @QuantumDot I don't really see how far that is from guessing, as my intention of using mathematica is to guess the assumption (using $\Delta$ and $\nabla$) for the inductive proof, which I believe is how the generalized Leibniz rule is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Nest[Laplacian[#, {x, y}] &, f[x, y], n]
```

where instead of `f[x,y]` you will substitute whatever you need. I used 2D for shortness, but even then it is long enough.  Then, for instance, with n=2 and f=u*v you get

```
Nest[Laplacian[#, {x, y}] &, u[x, y]*v[x, y], 2] // Simplify
```

with the effect

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry but this isn't quite what I intended to ask...but it seems useful indeed in its own right, thanks.